# Two Way binding in template

Tags: angular

Im facing a problem when making two way binding in an Async variable.

when binding the variable to an async obj, it fails to do so cause of the object dot notation.

```
{{data.wageStatement?.canton.abreviation}}
```

i tryed using `{{data.wageStatement?['canton.abreviation'] }}` or `{{data.wageStatement['canton.abreviation'] }}` but its not working

plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/YA7YNDBcXLxxHDP3zU5v?p=preview

Comment: Here is the working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/PiKRjfoj2dIB66HLduMz?p=preview

Comment: yes , but the name of the key is :       "canton.abbreviation"

Comment: That's what he wrote. You can't name something with a period in it if you don't want it treated as an object. What he wrote equates a `canton` object that has a `abreviation` field. That's what you wanted, right?

Comment: @AgonFejza Your app.ts has abreviation